# dynode createtable with shema

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to implement dynode to talk with dynamodb form a node.js script.
There are several examples on the Internet that shows how to do that with dynode, such as:

```
var opts = {read: 20, write: 25, hash: {name: String}, range: {age: Number}};
dynode.createTable("ExampleTable", opts, console.log);
```

which actually does the trick and works for me...
The issues I'm having is that I need to implement a shema on the same time when I create the database, or at least after that, a shema means that I need to tell the dynamodb to add a first_name field with string format, an address with string format etc...
there is no way nor instructions that shows how to do that ...

It's annoying to spend so much time on a so simple issue, because it is not well documented...
[here is the dynode github web site](https://github.com/Wantworthy/dynode):

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't have schemas (if that's what you mean).

You can't force the table to represent a fixed set of attributes.

You can make sure in your application code that each item you store in the table will have the attributes you require, but the DynamoDB API won't enforce it.

Look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) how to build your Item objects before putting them in db

Comment: but I still need to tell it that a table has like a number ID, a name string etc before pushing these datas ... how do we tell it that after the createtable ?